# Number of packages per repository (major distributions)

Tags: linux-distributions, packages, repository

Is there a website where i can find how many packages the major distributions have?

Comment: Note that some distributions split development headers and often documentation into separate packages, so a simple "package count" is often meaningless. A somewhat extreme example would be {`libgtk2.0-0`, `libgtk2.0-bin`, `libgtk2.0-common`, `libgtk2.0-dev`, `libgtk2.0-doc`} on Debian versus {`gtk2`} on Arch.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions#Package_management_and_installation) keeps the probably most comprehensive and updated list.

Another question is why it would matter to you; package count does not say much in itself, and to the largest part, all the "big" packages are available for all distributions.

Comment: It has nothing to do with selection of a distribution, just curiosity. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/) gives an approximate but keep in mind that it is showing only binary packages, also architectures do not have same level of support.

   Usually, a source package is built and sliced into multiple deliverables.

   Example Debian is estimated to have 30K source packages, 59K binary packages on [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/).
2. One way to get exact count without installing any, is by downloading the source packages manifest/index from official repositories/pools or their mirrors. Then pass it through an `zgrep|wc -l` filter.

   Free distributions like Debian/Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSuse ... all have public repository with meta.

   Example of:

- Fedora mirror: https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/source/tree/repodata/

  ```
        Name    Last modified   Size

    [ ] 1adc7f7f68727884a1cfdd5ed6a779da153f2943529eab8e22242cafd781473d-other.xml.gz   2022-02-24 18:44    3.6M
    [ ] 4a7e634ca3f6fbfd7af872c5bee66d53040da1a333a7d03f9e4fc81710da194a-other.sqlite.xz    2022-02-24 18:44    4.1M
    [ ] 7fb9cc4420874bbe652d5a8db6e5ffedcbb96cbda355a20a2c012834570ebb15-filelists.xml.gz   2022-02-24 18:44    1.8M
    [TXT]   38e4373598b7d48ea0b348ec5d5e8dacdb50c9aea350ad71bc5df7f94c6f670d-other.xml.zck  2022-02-24 18:44    3.2M
    [ ] 2235c627ffd843ae45a32a1f502c6546e121acb848c9aa83a8e2fa163c3b16fe-primary.xml.gz 2022-02-24 18:44    6.8M
    [TXT]   aa34aca085b179988fe455ed82a6f39b98ac24501b089a24db867d4b13827251-filelists.xml.zck  2022-02-24 18:44    1.8M
    [ ] b5b7b1dd42bc58a7ea7ebbd0a825f77961797d2994c10186b3745253d943e806-filelists.sqlite.xz    2022-02-24 18:44    1.7M
    [TXT]   bc278431b67a343cff3b3794c6a422d4a6a31f9a3bbe34fbe9d8654566334a18-primary.xml.zck    2022-02-24 18:44    6.2M
    [ ] bd645c35a0003ea67175f31e937407cb685941e1269c3a1d47a49a32405d54d1-primary.sqlite.xz  2022-02-24 18:45    8.6M
    [TXT]   repomd.xml  2022-02-24 18:45    4.9K
  ```
- Ubuntu mirror: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/jammy/

  ```
    ../
    by-hash/                                           15-Oct-2021 12:15       -
    main/                                              10-Nov-2021 22:59       -
    multiverse/                                        11-Nov-2021 03:59       -
    restricted/                                        10-Nov-2021 23:13       -
    universe/                                          11-Nov-2021 00:23       -
    Contents-amd64.gz                                  26-Feb-2022 04:57     44M
    Contents-i386.gz                                   26-Feb-2022 05:24     35M
    InRelease                                          26-Feb-2022 15:25    264K
    Release                                            26-Feb-2022 15:25    263K
    Release.gpg                                        26-Feb-2022 15:25     819
  ```